# Alternative of findAll that return exact value, not the matches value?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

**List findAll(@Nullable Specification spec)** return all value that matches the Specification .

Example: If in specification i have a parameter = 3.0 , findAll return me all the value matches.
So it return for example 543.0 , but i want just 3.0

Do you know a function that return me just the values that are exactly that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reserch I don t discover any predefined method. 
So I rezolved this with a @Query

```
@Query(Select t FROM Table t Where (t.price= :priceValue or null= :priceValue) and ( t.location= :locationValue or null= :locationValue) 
List<Entity> getAllWithExactValue(@Param("priceValue") String priceValue, @Param("locationValue") String locationValue);
```

This let you have endpoints like this:

```
localhost:8080/param?locationValue=ClujNapoca&priceValue=1234
```

or

```
 localhost:8080/param?priceValue=1234
```

or

```
localhost:8080/param?locationValue=ClujNapoca
```

And in return we will receive just variables with the exact value we asked

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
List findBySpecification(@Nullable Specification spec)
```

How your database tables look like?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you don't need `Specification`.

Assuming that you want to fetch a list of `YourObject` based on the value of a field named `price`, you just have to add a method in the repository interface :

```java
public interface YourObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<YourObject, Short>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<YourObject> {
    public List<YourObject> findByPrice(Double price);
}
```

Spring will automaticaly implements the prototype as you want it : fetching all `YourObject`s that have field price equaks to the value given in parameter.

Comment: In Specification i have multiple variable. Example i want to find by student, by id, by year but all in one .So I need specification

Comment: I understand. Could you edit your post and show us what is your code at the moment, please?